# Does the fragment manager restore the last displayed fragment on screen after orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The app consists of an activity (containing a `FrameLayout` only) and three `Fragments` (all of them same in structure, have a button but the only difference being different background color).

When the activity is first created, all fragments are put into the `FrameLayout` one by one by replacing. When we click the button (of the fragment) on the screen, it replaces the current fragment with another fragment.

The problem being that on screen rotation, the activity shows the fragment which was displayed when the app was first started, irrespective of the fragment that was being displayed just before rotation.

Why does this happen? Why isn't the last displayed fragment restored on the screen?

I know that I can use `onSavedInstanceState`, but more importantly, I want to learn how the FragmentManager works.

The Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityInstance {

    fraga a;
    fragb b;
    fragc c;
    FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


        if (fm.findFragmentByTag("a")!=null){
            a  = (fraga) fm.findFragmentByTag("a");
        }
        else {
            a = new fraga();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.frame, a, "a" );
            ft.commit();
        }

        if (fm.findFragmentByTag("b")!=null){
            b  = (fragb) fm.findFragmentByTag("b");
        }
        else {
            b = new fragb();
            FragmentTransaction fx = fm.beginTransaction();
            fx.add(R.id.frame, b, "b" );
            fx.commit();
        }

        if (fm.findFragmentByTag("c")!=null){
            c  = (fragc) fm.findFragmentByTag("c");
        }
        else {
            c = new fragc();
            FragmentTransaction fl = fm.beginTransaction();
            fl.add(R.id.frame, c, "c" );
            fl.commit();
        }
    }

    public void changefrag(int i) { //This method is called by the fragment 
                                     using the ActivityInstance interface
        switch (i){
            case 1: FragmentTransaction f1 = fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, a, "a" );
                    f1.commit();
                    break;
            case 2: FragmentTransaction f2 = fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, b, "b" );
                    f2.commit();
                    break;
            case 3: FragmentTransaction f3 = fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, c, "c" );
                    f3.commit();
                    break;
            default:
                    {Toast.makeText(this, "default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `FragmentManager` restores the last displayed `fragment` after orientation change. Looks like you are adding a new `fragment` after every orientation change from the `Activity`. So a new fragment is added over the last fragment, which covers the last fragment.

You should add your `fragment` in `onCreate` only if the  `savedInstanceState` is null. `savedInstanceState` will be null only the first time, it won't be null after orientation change.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // add your fragment
} 
// else -  don't add fragment, because all the fragments are restored automatically
```

Comment: But I am first checking IF the fragments existed before rotation. If not then only I am adding the fragments in the ELSE blocks. Am I right? @Bob

Comment: Because you are calling replace when you click the button. Replace removes all the added fragments in the container and adds only the latest fragment you pass. So if you replace with the fragc, the fraga and fragb are gone. After orientation change, those fragments will be added again. More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int, android.app.Fragment, java.lang.String)